# Extract price "with $" from sentence

Tags: python, regex

data = "General usage $34.45 and others $4.7."

```py
r = re.compile(r'$(\d[\d.,]*)\b')
possible_prices = [x.replace(',', '') for x in re.findall(r, v)]
```

Expected result : `possible prices = ['34.45', '4.7']`

Result recieved : `[]`

How can I extract only the price values? Why does my regex doesn't work? It works for euro.

Comment: `$` means the end of the string (with optional newline) in regex. `\$` means a literal `$` character.

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> re.findall( r'\$([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)', v)
['34.45', '4.7']
```

Comment: It is possible that the intended string can contain other number combinations as well. The regex should only extract values starting with '$'.

Comment: @Loki it took 2 characters to address your problem...

Answer (score 0):

$ means the end of the string (with optional newline) in regex. \$ means a literal $ character.

```
r = re.compile(r'\$(\d[\d.,]*)\b')
possible_prices = [x.replace(',', '') for x in re.findall(r, v)]
```